# Schema.org places all the same location in Google results

Tags: google-search, schema.org, google-rich-snippets

I started using schema.org on the events displayed on my site some time ago and Google finally shows my results on their search results.
I wish they didn't, because they place all my events on an obscure rugby field somewhere in my town, and I can't understand why.

So first, here is a screenshot of the results from a Google search:

> [image: Google search results]

The first two results don't come from my site, but the next results are,
they all are on "Gymnase municipal Fournier" or "Terrain de rugby" depending on which domain name they were indexed from.

Let's concentrate on the ones located in "Terrain de rugby", for example, "le dessin vient en chemin" supposed to happen on July, Saturday the 18th, here is where it got the information from: http://metz.fr/agenda/fiche-14368.php

Here is a link to its analysis by Google Structured Data Testing Tool: https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool?url=http%253A%252F%252Fmetz.fr%252Fagenda%252Ffiche-14368.php

1) The testing tool says it's able to get a correct place, it shows me that place, the latitude longitude is correctly placed (certainly not on the rugby field anyway).

2) In the Google Webmasters Tools, under structured data, I can see that it indexed my events properly, their location is right.

3) This rugby field is not even in the geographical center of the town, it's quite the opposite, it's on the outskirts of the town.

Anybody has an explanation as to why they always end up on the rugby field, when everything Google says me is that place is ok (Testing Tool, place ok, structured data indexed, place ok)?

Optional question: WTH this particular rugby field? I could understand the geographical center of the town, the geometrical center, even its most significant place, the mayor office, but really not that.

Comment: Use [this link](https://www.google.fr/search?q=agenda+metz&hl=fr-&tbas=0&ei=gXasVaOLG8G4UpCWg-gN) to retrieve the results as seen from the French google in French language (events don't expand otherwise).  

[This event](http://metz.fr/agenda/fiche-14872.php) is one of those shown as the 'rugby pitch' but as far as I can tell that is where google maps thinks the center of Metz is.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the `PostalAddress` -

`streetAddress` means house or building number and road name - but Chapelle des Templiers does not have a house/building number.

`postalCode` means the area within Metz, 57000 covers most of Metz so google maps just uses the rugby field (believing this to be the center). It is like the American zipcode - 90210 is Bevelry Hills (a large area, not a road).

the values should be:

```
http://schema.org/PostalAddress
streetAddress     Rue de la Citadelle
postalCode        57000
addressLocality   Metz
addressCountry    France
```

Because *Chapelle des Templiers* has it's own website, you can set the `url` inside `PostalAddress` to the location (`url` is inherited from `Thing`), or you can use the url from [wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chapelle_des_Templiers_de_Metz) to identify the location within Metz.

Comment: thank you for your comment. we have very complex addresses like this one : "1, parvis des Droits-de-l’Homme CS 90490 57020 Metz Cedex 1" all the big places (places that have the biggest events, in general) all have very complex addresses. I have geo cordinates for all of them, wouldn't it be more practical to give only the name and the geo coordinates ?

Comment: that sounds like a great idea, you can use the `geo` property inside Place rather than splitting up the address http://schema.org/geo

Comment: I just put the `geo` information on the place, I completely removed the `address` but Google Structured Data Testing Tool complained that it was missing, so I put it back, but only with the locality.